# How to pass data from function to external object (android)

Tags: android, button, barcode

im using this impimentation of ZyXEL barcode scanner and i want to pass the string 'upc' to an EditText object out of this function,
how can i do this?

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    switch(requestCode) 
    {
        case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
        {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) 

               {
                            IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                            if (scanResult != null)
                            {
                            String upc = scanResult.getContents();

                            }

               }
                break;
                }
            }
        }
```

SECOND QUESTION:

i want to call a function after clicking a button like this:

```
button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

             IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);

        }
    });
```

but i get this error:

> "The method initiateScan(Activity) in the type IntentIntegrator is not
>   applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){})"

so ive tried to solve this problem by calling to function when clicking this button which this funtction call the original function

it's look like this:

```
 button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             turntheshiton();

        }
    });

 public void turntheshiton()
{
    IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);
}
```

but it's not real elegant way to solve this out, there is any other way?

thanks!!

Comment: in IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this); what you want to pass activity ref or listner ref ? if activity then use <activity-name>.this like Activity.this

Comment: in first question, what is the issue in calling any function having string argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 String upc = scanResult.getContents();
 updateEditField(upc );// or use <activity-name>.this.updateEditField(upc );




private void updateEditField(String str){

EditField ef = (EditField)findViewByID(R.id.<ef_id>);

        if(null!=ef){
           ef.setText(str):
      }
}
```

SECOND QUESTION:

```
in IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);



use <activity-name>.this like Activity.this
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but im trying to use MyActivity.this and it says: 
"The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Comment: here:
     button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
   public void onClick(View v)//here i get this error
            {
             MyActivity.this
                                
            }
        });

Comment: try this          button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override public void onClick(View v)//here i get this error
 { 
   MyActivity.this.initiateScan(MyActivity.this);
 } 
 }
 );

Comment: Ok, now it's working! maybe i didt got you right but i wrote it like this:  IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(MyActivity.this);

BTW, can you explain to me why the just "IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);" didnt work?

Comment: because this line "initiateScan(this)" is inside the anonymous class (listener) not in activity. so only this will give you the reference of listener instance.